# Getting error while creating deployment object of mysql :Upgrade after a crash is not supported. This redo log was created with MySQL 5.7.42

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

**Error:- **
2023-07-09T12:49:14.969217Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 24
2023-07-09T12:49:14.976050Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-09T12:49:15.007289Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade after a crash is not supported. This redo log was created with MySQL 5.7.42. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
2023-07-09T12:49:15.007455Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-07-09T12:49:15.496366Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-07-09T12:49:15.496610Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-07-09T12:49:15.496702Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-09T12:49:15.497324Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

**yaml file:-**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  selector: # mysql Pod Should contain same labels
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
      tier: database
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: # Must match 'Service' and 'Deployment' selectors
        app: mysql
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23 # image from docker-hub
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: root
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE # Setting Database Name from a 'ConfigMap'
              value: javatechie
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:        # Mounting voulume obtained from Persistent Volume Claim
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql #This is the path in the container on which the mounting will take place.
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage # Obtaining 'vloume' from PVC
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

please help me identify why its happening??

I was expecting pod to be created but its constantly showing error